# Wordcloud with a specific letter

Tags: r, wordcloud2

I have created a wordcloud which contains Twitter mentions for February no problem. However, I want to be able to edit it, firstly I tried to create a wordcloud using the Twitter logo and when that was unsuccessful I tried making one using the letter T. However this was also unsuccessful and i'm not sure why or how to resolve the issue. I'll input the code below so you can see where I'm going wrong.

```
.libPaths("M:/R")
library("tm")
library("SnowballC")
library("wordcloud")
library("RColorBrewer")
library("wordcloud2")
library("magrittr")
library("tidytext")

get_sentiments("afinn")
get_sentiments("bing")
get_sentiments("nrc")

#Loading the data as a corpus
corpus <- Corpus(DirSource(directory = "//ecfle35/STAFF-HOME$/MaxEmery/Twitter mentions"))

inspect(corpus)

#Remove special characters
toSpace <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern) gsub(pattern, "", x))
docs <- tm_map(corpus, toSpace, "/")
docs <- tm_map(corpus, toSpace, "@")
docs <- tm_map(corpus, toSpace, "\|")

#Convert the text to lower case
docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower))
#Remove numbers
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)
#Remove english common stopwords
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
#specify your stopwrods as a character vector
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, c("exetercollege", "exeter", "execollsport", "pitchatpalace", "execolljapan", "day", "today", "sponsorship","thank", "http", "see", "https", "will", "exeapprentices", "business", "well", "first", "microsofteduk", "apprenticeships", "new", "looking", "team", "skills", "entrepreneurs", "microsoft"))
#Remove punctuations
docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)
#Get rid of extra white spaces
docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)
#Text stemming (strip off common suffixes)
docs <- tm_map(docs, stemDocument)

#Build a term-document matrix (a table containing the frequency of the words)
dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs)
m <- as.matrix(dtm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m), decreasing = TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word= names(v), freq=v)
head(d, 10)

#Generate the word cloud
set.seed(1234)
wordcloud(words = d$word, freq = d$freq, min.freq = 1,
max.words = 200, random.order = FALSE, rot.per = 0.35,
colors = brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))

#Change the shape of the wordcloud

letterCloud(corpus, word = "T", color='random-light' , backgroundColor="black")

#Change the shape using your image
wordcloud2(demoFreq, figpath= "twitter.png", size= 1.5, color= "skyblue", backgroundColor="black")
```

I want to be able to use my corpus so I can create different shapes and use different images for my wordcloud.

Instead when I try to enter the following code I get an error message:

```
> letterCloud(corpus, word = "T", color='random-light' , backgroundColor="black")

Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘c("SimpleCorpus", "Corpus")’ to a data.frame
```

Comment: `letterCloud` has for long not been able to make letterClouds. I don't know if there has been any update(fix) for this issue. You can check the GitHub repo for `wordcloud2`.

Comment: I didn't know that thanks for saving me time! I tried using wordcloud2 but it's saying: Error in wordcloud2(docs, word = "T", color = "random-light", backgroundColor = "black") : 
  unused argument (word = "T")

Comment: check using shapes and masks in a `geom_text_wordcloud` for a `ggplot` graph with the packages `ggwordcloud` and `ggplot2`